# VBA Turn .selection from Word Document into a string

Tags: vba, string, selection

Good Evening. I've been trying to transform a whole Word doc into a string. My current problem is that I can open the doc, select the text, but I can't manage to transform into a string. Funny thing is that a msgbox print the text on the screen.

```
    Dim s_txt as string
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True

    s_arq = Cells(1, i_col)
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\TCC\pdf2doc\" & s_arq)

    wrdApp.Selection.WholeStory
    wrdApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

    MsgBox(wrdApp.Selection)
    s_txt = wrdApp.Selection

    wrdApp.Quit
```

When I try to get the string s_txt it returns nothing. But the msgbox print the text perfectly.
I tried selection.text, and it returns nothing.

Comment: Don't show doing anything with s_txt. `Debug.Print s_txt` works for me.

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand. I need s_txt to store the selected text from doc.

Comment: Ok i think i get. Somehow, the value of the string is not showing when a hover over it

Comment: You set a breakpoint and step through code? Has the line executed already when you hover over it? Use Debug.Print?

Comment: Hey June. It seems that when i hover over a named string, it shows (s_txt="), with only one quotation.

I though the string was not getting passed. The Debug.print was i tool that i never used.

Comment: I cannot replicate issue so cannot advise solution.